# Confluent set-up: Using python script as source to a JDBC sink

Tags: python, postgresql, jdbc, apache-kafka-connect

Newbie to Kafka and Confluent here...

So I've followed this nice little tutorial on getting a MySQL database connected to a Kafka stream: https://github.com/confluentinc/demo-scene/tree/master/kafka-to-database.
Got everything working properly.

Now, I'm trying to get the same idea down but with the source being a python script where a producer sends randomly generated data to a topic while Kafka Connect sends those changes to a PostgreSQL database.
I'm running confluent standalone mode and successfully got a PostgreSQL database connected as a sink.
However, when I send messages to the topic through a python script, it doesn't write to the PostgreSQL database. Is sending messages from a producer not the same as running data from a stream? If so, how could I get it running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> from a producer not the same as running data from a stream

Unclear what this means. "A Stream" in ksqlDB is still using a producer internally.

> it doesn't write to the PostgreSQL database.

Look at the Connect process/server logs for errors, not the database.

---

You need a schema for your events to use the JDBC connector. ksqlDB adds a schema for you... you cannot send plain strings (or JSON without `schema` and `payload` fields).

https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-converters-serialization-explained/

See producer examples available from Confluent for using Python with the Schema Registry - https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/tree/master/examples

Comment: I've successfully been able to create a producer and sent the value with the correct schema (via this tutorial: https://betterprogramming.pub/avro-producer-with-python-and-confluent-kafka-library-4a1a2ed91a24). 

I can query the results on ksql when using SELECT * FROM <topic> but the records aren't being pushed to the PostgreSQL database it's supposed to be connected to.

Also, I do regularly check the connect logs using "confluent local services connect log" but no errors are coming up.

Comment: As mentioned, use /status endpoint of the Connect server. That's where task errors are shown. And you don't need ksql for this

Comment: Thanks for all your help! I finally got data getting written to the database. The issue I was having turns out to be a strange behavior with keys not getting pushed along with the rest of the message. Still experimenting to see if the issue is with the library or with my connector configs.